# Send variable value from view to mysql

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my cart I have a value that I need send to order_items, I have sent my variable to view and it's displaying correctly, but when save order, the value return NULL. I have checked all data, but probably the problem is how I'm sending.

Controller:

```
$dataProdutos['detalhesEstoque'] = $this->produtos_model->detalhesEstoque('23');
```

View: Displaying correctly.

```
<?= $detalhesEstoque[0]->codprod ?>
```

How I'm trying to send to MySQL using this variable:

```
$detalhesEstoque[0]->codprod;
```

Comment: sending to db, means using POST, right

Comment: Yes, I tried using _POST['codprod'] that is my input, that receive my value =$detalhesEstoque[0]->codprod; but, not work.

Comment: that's the way to do it, but you need to get the names right: the name field of the form element (e.g. input) needs to match your database table column field, to keep it as simple as possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send variable data from your view to controller then save to database using POST method

for example
at view

```
    <form action="<?php echo site_url('datasave/save_action'); ?>" method="post">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" name="codprod" id="codprod" value="<?php echo $detalhesEstoque[0]->codprod; ?>" readonly ?>
    </form>
```

at controller

```
       public function save_action() 
         {
              $data= array(
               'codprod' => $this->input->post('codprod',TRUE),
                );

       $this->Codprod_model->insert($data);
```

at model

```
function insert($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('codprodtable', $data);
}
```